# How configure aws glue jobs to use column types from glue datalake table definition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-glue

Consider the following aws glue job code:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

medicare_dynamicframe = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database = "my_database",
    table_name = "my_table")
medicare_dynamicframe.printSchema()

job.commit()
```

It prints something like that (note that `price_key` is **not** on second position):

```
root
|-- day_key: string
...
|-- price_key: string
```

While `my_table` in datalake is defined with `day_key` as `int` (first column) and `price_key` as `decimal(25,0)` (second column).

May be I am wrong but I spot from sources that aws glue uses table and database to get just s3 path to data but completelly ignores any type definitions. May be for some data formats like `parquet` it is normal, but not for `csv`.

How configure aws glue to set schema from datalake table defintion for dynamic frame with csv?